# Run Flask on demand to visualize computed data

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Using Python 3.7, I made a CLI utility which prints some results to stdout. Depending on an option the results should be visualized in a browser (single user, no sessions). Flask seems to be a good choice for this. However, this is not a standard usecase described in the docs or in tutorials.

I am looking for a best practise way to pass the data (e.g. a Python List) to the Flask app so that I can return it from view functions. Basically it would be immutable application data. The following seems to work but I don't like to use globals:

main.py:

```py
import myapp

result = compute_stuff()
if show_in_browser:
  myapp.data = result
  myapp.app.run()
```

myapp.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from typing import List

app = Flask(__name__)
result: List

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return f"items: {len(result)}"
```

Reading the Flask docs I get the impression I should use an application context. On the other hand, its lifetime does not span across requests and I would not know how to populate it. Reading other questions I might use a Flask config object because it seems to be available on every request. But this is not really about configuration. Or maybe I should use [Klein](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077464/35657) answer?

Comment: Would your visualization involve just a single HTML page or could it be multiple?

Comment: It would be more than a just static page. Parts of it could be solved with JS but I'd prefer to use Python. And there will be interactions with the host system, e.g. the local filesystem.

Comment: Okay, I had in mind to suggest simply using Jinja to generate the HTML, store in a temp directory and load it onto the browser. If you need that level of interactions with the file system then you'll need something like Flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a best practice way. So I am going with a modification of my original approach:

```py
class MyData:
    pass

class MyApp(Flask):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(__name__)
        self.env = "development"
        self.debug = True

    def getData(self) -> MyData:
        return self._my_data

    def setMyData(self, my_data: MyData) -> None:
        self._my_data = my_data

app = MyApp()
```

This way I can set the data after the `app` instance was already created - which is necessary to be able to use it in routing decorators defined outside of the class. It would be nice to have more encapsulation: use `app` methods for routing (with decorators) instead of module global functions accessing a module global `app` object. Apparently that is not flaskic.